# Bootstrap Table columns not aligning properly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a table that appears to not like to be formatted properly. I've tried adjusting the colspans but nothing has worked. There's an extra column header on the right that should say "Operations" but it goes outside the div (or something) and I can't even scroll to it and none of the rows match their headers. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

javascript

```
<script>
  var $table = $('#table')
  var $remove = $('#remove')
  var selections = []
    document.getElementById("Add").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "new.php";
    };

  function getIdSelections() {
    return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
      return row.id
    })
  }

  function responseHandler(res) {


    $.each (res.rows, function (i, row) {
      row.state = $.inArray(row.id, selections) !== -1
    })
    return res
  }

  function detailFormatter(index, row) {
    var html = []
    $.each(row, function (key, value) {
      html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>')
    })
    return html.join('')
  }

function operateFormatter(value, row, index) { 
return [
 '<a class="remove" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this vendor?\')" href="deleteVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="Remove">', 
'<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', 
'</a>', '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="View">',
 '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', '</a>' ].join(''); }

  window.operateEvents = {
    'click .view': function (e, value, row, index) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("id", row);

    },

  }

  function totalTextFormatter(data) {
    return 'Total'
  }

  function totalNameFormatter(data) {
    return data.length
  }

  function totalPriceFormatter(data) {
    var field = this.field
    return '$' + data.map(function (row) {
      return +row[field].substring(1)
    }).reduce(function (sum, i) {
      return sum + i
    }, 0)
  }

  function initTable() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({

      height: 700,
      locale: $('#locale').val(),
      columns: [
        [{
          field: 'state',
          checkbox: true,
          rowspan: 2,
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle'
        },  {
          title: 'Vendor',
          colspan: 1,
          align: 'center'
        },  {
          title: 'Vendor Details',
          colspan: 8,
          align: 'center'
        }],
        [{
          field: 'name',
          title: 'Vendor',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        },{
          field: 'account_company',
          title: 'Account Company',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        }, {
          field: 'id',
          title: 'Vendor ID',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        },  {
          field: 'residual',
          title: 'Residual Risk',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        }, 
        {
          field: 'company',
          title: 'Company',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },      {
          field: 'type',
          title: 'Type',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },{
          field: 'status',
          title: 'Status',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },
        {
          field: 'owner',
          title: 'Owner',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        }, 
        {
          field: 'operate',
          title: 'Operations',
          align: 'center',
          clickToSelect: false,
          events: window.operateEvents,
          formatter: operateFormatter
        },



        ]
      ]
    })
    $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
      'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table',
    function () {
      $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length)

      // save your data, here just save the current page
      selections = getIdSelections()
      // push or splice the selections if you want to save all data selections
    })
    $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
      console.log(name, args)
    })
    $remove.click(function () {
      var ids = getIdSelections()
      $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: ids
      })
      $remove.prop('disabled', true)
    })
  }

  $(function() {
    initTable()

    $('#locale').change(initTable)
  })
</script>
```

HTML format for table insertion

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-show-fullscreen="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
  data-detail-view="true"
  data-show-export="true"
  data-click-to-select="true"
  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
  data-minimum-count-columns="2"
  data-show-pagination-switch="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-id-field="id"
  data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
  data-side-pagination="client"
   data-url="ajax.php" 
  data-response-handler="responseHandler" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <tr>                                                                        
            <th data-field="name">Vendor</th>
            <th data-field="account_company">Account Company</th>
            <th data-field="id">Vendor ID</th>
            <th data-field="residual">Residual Risk</th>
            <th data-field="company">Company</th>
            <th data-field="type">Type</th>
            <th data-field="status">Status</th>
            <th data-field="owner">Owner</th>
        </tr>                       
        </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

EDIT: When I zoom all the way out on the page, I can fully see the table and they appear to line up fairly decently. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First I made sure your HTML was semantically correct at validator.nu and it has semantic issue with no cells in your thead.

You also need a tbody with trs and tds that match the thead for everything to line up. I see JavaScript errors too but didn't debug those.

You have nested a tr (table row) in another which is also incorrect so I removed the extra one.

With the proper HTML the table works:

```js
 var $table = $('#table')
  var $remove = $('#remove')
  var selections = []
    document.getElementById("Add").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "new.php";
    };

  function getIdSelections() {
    return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
      return row.id
    })
  }

  function responseHandler(res) {


    $.each (res.rows, function (i, row) {
      row.state = $.inArray(row.id, selections) !== -1
    })
    return res
  }

  function detailFormatter(index, row) {
    var html = []
    $.each(row, function (key, value) {
      html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>')
    })
    return html.join('')
  }

function operateFormatter(value, row, index) { 
return [
 '<a class="remove" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this vendor?\')" href="deleteVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="Remove">', 
'<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', 
'</a>', '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="View">',
 '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', '</a>' ].join(''); }

  window.operateEvents = {
    'click .view': function (e, value, row, index) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("id", row);

    },

  }

  function totalTextFormatter(data) {
    return 'Total'
  }

  function totalNameFormatter(data) {
    return data.length
  }

  function totalPriceFormatter(data) {
    var field = this.field
    return '$' + data.map(function (row) {
      return +row[field].substring(1)
    }).reduce(function (sum, i) {
      return sum + i
    }, 0)
  }

  function initTable() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({

      height: 700,
      locale: $('#locale').val(),
      columns: [
        [{
          field: 'state',
          checkbox: true,
          rowspan: 2,
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle'
        },  {
          title: 'Vendor',
          colspan: 1,
          align: 'center'
        },  {
          title: 'Vendor Details',
          colspan: 8,
          align: 'center'
        }],
        [{
          field: 'name',
          title: 'Vendor',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        },{
          field: 'account_company',
          title: 'Account Company',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        }, {
          field: 'id',
          title: 'Vendor ID',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        },  {
          field: 'residual',
          title: 'Residual Risk',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        }, 
        {
          field: 'company',
          title: 'Company',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },      {
          field: 'type',
          title: 'Type',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },{
          field: 'status',
          title: 'Status',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },
        {
          field: 'owner',
          title: 'Owner',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        }, 
        {
          field: 'operate',
          title: 'Operations',
          align: 'center',
          clickToSelect: false,
          events: window.operateEvents,
          formatter: operateFormatter
        },



        ]
      ]
    })
    $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
      'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table',
    function () {
      $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length)

      // save your data, here just save the current page
      selections = getIdSelections()
      // push or splice the selections if you want to save all data selections
    })
    $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
      console.log(name, args)
    })
    $remove.click(function () {
      var ids = getIdSelections()
      $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: ids
      })
      $remove.prop('disabled', true)
    })
  }

  $(function() {
    initTable()

    $('#locale').change(initTable)
  })
```

```css
table {
width: 100%;
}

td {
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table
  id="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-show-fullscreen="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
  data-detail-view="true"
  data-show-export="true"
  data-click-to-select="true"
  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
  data-minimum-count-columns="2"
  data-show-pagination-switch="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-id-field="id"
  data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
  data-side-pagination="client"
   data-url="ajax.php" 
  data-response-handler="responseHandler" >
    <thead>
        <tr>                                                                        
            <td data-field="name">Vendor</td>
            <td data-field="account_company">Account Company</td>
            <td data-field="id">Vendor ID</td>
            <td data-field="residual">Residual Risk</td>
            <td data-field="company">Company</td>
            <td data-field="type">Type</td>
            <td data-field="status">Status</td>
            <td data-field="owner">Owner</td>
        </tr>                       
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
            <td>Some data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The second set of <tr> is used to nest the table I believe. Whenever they are removed, the table crashes and cannot see the table. I believe they're used because they're child rows for each row. The initTable() loads data from ajax.php (database search). Anyways, I just got it working by simply resizing my page back to 100% zoom which I'm unsure when it got resized or why it impacted it.

Comment: To nest a table put an entirely new table (with its rows and cells) into the row.

Comment: Apologies I was wrong there is a th element that can be used for table headings. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/